# posts per page on a static page + pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, posts, static-site

Thanks for taking the time to check this out.

I've spend a couple days going over this.  Lots of time on wp.org but i'm just not getting it.  Should be an easy fix I'm sure.  No matter what i try, i can't limit the number of posts per page nor get any pagination to display.  This is my most recent attempt (maybe not my best attempt). The page just shows all the posts OR all the recent ones or something (not my site).  Once i can at least get the page to limit the posts, then i'll tackle the pagination.  Also, setting the posts per page in the WP dashboard does nothing...and never did. That's why i'm trying to code something myself.  Why can't i limit the number of posts per page?  Would i put the pagination where i currently have it?  Is this a total mess, lol?

Thanks again,

Dave (code below)

```
<?php /* Template Name: Stories */ ?>

<?php 

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- *************************************** -->    
    <div class="custom_two_third">

<?php

// The Query

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );



$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    }

// pagination
next_posts_link();
previous_posts_link();

} else {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
}



/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- custom_two_third -->
<?php 

    get_sidebar(); 

    get_footer(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using post_type

```
$args_articles =array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'order' => 'desc',
            'paged' => $paged
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. So then put the "$args_articles" in the "$the_query = new WP_Query();"?  If yes, no luck.

Comment: Please find the answer I posted below

Answer (score 0):

```
// the query
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$news_eve_args = array( 'post_type' => 'news_events', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged' => $paged);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $news_eve_args );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
          <?php the_title(); echo "<br/>"; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav>
      <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
      <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>                           
    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no news or events  at this time.', 'theme' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for you response.  When i use your exact code w/o "'post_type' => 'news_events'", I get a list of the same 11 titles.  The titles are separated by <br>s like the code states.  Could this be a problem with the way the posts are labeled, stored, etc, ?.

Comment: I think i just answered my own question.  The posts are labeled "sticky".  I'm new to WP.  I assume that means they'll be sticking around.  Most likely on the first page.  Is this the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, it will work in your case.

```
global $query_string;
query_posts("{$query_string}&posts_per_page=12");

while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ...
}
```